# C#: Accessing elements in MultiValueDictionary without loop

Tags: c#, collections, multi-value-dictionary

I'm using `MultiValueDictionary` from [Microsoft.Experimental.Collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections) by this way:

```
MultiValueDictionary<string, string> multiValueDictionary = new MultiValueDictionary<string, string>();

multiValueDictionary.Add("Device A", "My Device");
multiValueDictionary.Add("Device A", "/dev/sda");
multiValueDictionary.Add("Device A", "123456789");
```

How can I retrieve(directly) the elements/values **without** using any loop?

Comment: Using [`TryGetValue`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs#L811) method?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it returns collection of `IReadOnlyCollection<TValue>` with 3 values... then how to retrieve it's elements?

Comment: You can try string.Join(',', multiValueDictionary["Device A"]);

Comment: It depens on what are you going to do with this data. You can also use LINQ and apply some function to all the results.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub You can use linq, can get enumerator, or create a list of values and access them by index. What is issue with using a loop? Iterating a collection is a very basic operation

Comment: @OguzOzgul `string.Join` while using Collection? that's wrong way / bad idea.

Comment: Then would you like to update your question and inform us how you are going to use the multi - values? You already retrieved the values of Device A when you access it like dict[] or dict.TryGetValue(), then what?

Comment: @OguzOzgul In this case, `TryGetValue(),` returns `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`, but I dont wan't use LINQ to access it's elements. Or I could already use `Dictionary<string, Model/Type>` instead.

Comment: There seems to be no direct way other than hacking into the InnerCollectionView (https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs) and getting the `_collection` field which is a List`1.